Using Poisson Distribution to Build GLM in R. Using "offset"
I am having trouble building a GLM model using the Poisson distribution. I am studying the effect of variables on the number of birds (4 variables in total). My dependent variable "density" has non-integer numbers and an error occurs. I do not want to round the numbers (this will reduce the accuracy of my data), and I do not want to use quasi-Poisson (quasi-Poisson distribution does not give an AIC value). Therefore, as an alternative to "density", I also added two new variables: "birds" and "area", given that "density" = "birds" / "area".
Example<-structure(list(birds = c(9L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 
5L, 2L), area = c(3.55, 2.52, 1.49, 1, 1.13, 1.49, 1.4, 0.57, 
1.11, 1.78, 1.63), density = c(2.5, 0.8, 1.3, 4, 0.9, 0.7, 2.9, 
1.8, 4.5, 2.8, 1.2), green = c(5.95, 5.62, 6.32, 6.04, 4.91, 
5.36, 7.15, 5.22, 6.8, 6.69, 6.47), open = c(3.69, 5, 3.94, 4.05, 
3.48, 3.97, 4.12, 4.29, 4.29, 3.56, 4), distance = c(0.6, 3, 
1, 0.9, 1, 1, 2.5, 3.2, 3.8, 2.5, 3), human = c(21.29, 22.76, 
23.02, 20.88, 21.26, 21.87, 23.19, 21.82, 19.49, 21.68, 19.6)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-11L))

fix(Example) # data table

To build the GLM model, I used the "offset(log…)" function.
I used the following code:
model = glm (birds ~ green + human + distance + open + offset (log (area)),
data = Example, family = poisson (link = "log"))

After manually building all possible models, I began to doubt the results of the obtained data. The model with the least influential factor "open" was in the top 3 models, which is an artifact. My doubts are related to the fact that before building the models, I tried to pre-estimate the influence of variables on density separately using Student's correlation (green r=0.59, human r = – 0.38, distance r = 0.21, open = r – 0.06). This pre-estimate using Student's correlation showed that "open" has the lowest correlation with "density". Applying the obtained estimate, I did not expect to see "open" in the best models. Therefore, I doubt the correctness of building the command in R using the function "offset(log…)".
I compared the models using compareGLM, using AICc values for small samples.
compareGLM(model.1, model.2, model.3, model.4, model.5, model.6, model.7, model.8, model.9, model.10, model.11, model.12, model.13, model.14, model.15)

$Models
   Formula                                                     
1  "birds ~ green + human + distance + open + offset(log(area))"
2  "birds ~ green + human + distance + offset(log(area))"       
3  "birds ~ green + human + offset(log(area))"                  
4  "birds ~ green + offset(log(area))"                          
5  "birds ~ human + offset(log(area))"                          
6  "birds ~ distance + offset(log(area))"                       
7  "birds ~ human + distance + offset(log(area))"               
8  "birds ~ open + offset(log(area))"                           
9  "birds ~ green + open + offset(log(area))"                   
10 "birds ~ green + distance + offset(log(area))"               
11 "birds ~ open + distance + offset(log(area))"                
12 "birds ~ open + human + offset(log(area))"                   
13 "birds ~ green + open + distance + offset(log(area))"        
14 "birds ~ green + open + human + offset(log(area))"           
15 "birds ~ open + distance + human + offset(log(area))"        

$Fit.criteria
   Rank Df.res   AIC  AICc   BIC McFadden Cox.and.Snell Nagelkerke p.value
1     5      6 48.17 69.17 50.55   0.2506        0.6669     0.6753 0.05776
2     4      7 46.23 58.23 48.22   0.2493        0.6651     0.6735 0.03640
3     3      8 45.53 52.20 47.13   0.2222        0.6228     0.6306 0.03394
4     2      9 44.58 48.01 45.77   0.2006        0.5852     0.5925 0.02195
5     2      9 47.41 50.84 48.61   0.1419        0.4634     0.4692 0.15350
6     2      9 48.88 52.31 50.07   0.1115        0.3869     0.3918 2.02200
7     3      8 49.41 56.07 51.00   0.1420        0.4636     0.4694 0.23540
8     2      9 48.02 51.45 49.22   0.1292        0.4327     0.4382 0.27070
9     3      8 45.98 52.65 47.57   0.2130        0.6073     0.6149 0.04238
10    3      8 46.03 52.69 47.62   0.2120        0.6055     0.6132 0.04340
11    3      8 49.21 55.88 50.80   0.1460        0.4731     0.4790 0.21340
12    3      8 48.97 55.64 50.57   0.1510        0.4843     0.4904 0.18950
13    4      7 47.87 59.87 49.86   0.2153        0.6112     0.6189 0.07186
14    4      7 47.13 59.13 49.12   0.2307        0.6365     0.6445 0.05315
15    4      7 50.72 62.72 52.71   0.1562        0.4961     0.5024 0.19730

What am I doing wrong using offset? Are there other ways to apply the Poisson distribution to my example?
Thanks in advance.

Why do you think that the counterintuitive results are related to using an offset?

Can you please edit your question to explain why you want to run a Poisson model with a response that takes non-integer values? It is almost always a mistake to do so - the usual way to model density is to make total counts the response variable and use log(area) as an offset - this is then effectively modeling density.

I'd be happy to post an answer explaining my logic, but if you're sure you want to do it the way you currently have it set up (which I'm 99% sure is incorrect) I won't bother ...

I ran your models, and I concluded that none of the independent variables are helpful.  Even with the best model (#4), the coefficient of "green" is only barely significant at the 95% level, and, when we consider that we are comparing 15 (related) models, that's not really significant at all.   Also note that 8 of your 15 models have "open" in them, so it's not that surprising that one of your top three models has "open" in it.

Michael M, I edited my text. My doubts are related to the fact that before building the models, I tried to pre-estimate the influence of variables on density separately using Student's correlation (green r=0.59, human r = – 0.38, distance r = 0.21, open = r – 0.06). This pre-estimate using Student's correlation showed that "open" has the lowest correlation with "density". Applying the obtained estimate, I did not expect to see "open" in the best models. Therefore, I doubt the correctness of building the command in R using the function "offset(log…)".

Ben Bolker, I edited my question.

Ben Bolker, I'd be glad to know your logic for constructing the model.

jbowman, thaks. I have additionally included a description of my doubts regarding “open” in my text.

jbowman, when using the command "anova(model.1)" statistically significant result only for "green", p=0,03736.

tl;dr you're probably not doing anything wrong.
Multivariate regression often leads to conclusions about the effects of predictor variables that differ from the conclusions of univariate regressions (or correlation analyses) using one predictor at a time. The only situation where this cannot happen is when the effects of the predictors are all independent, which essentially only happens in linear models (not GLMs) where the predictors are all orthogonal to each other (which in turn usually only happens in designed, balanced experiments, not in observational data).
Otherwise (the typical case in GLMs on observational data), the effects you see are all conditional on the effects of all of the other covariates.
Cross Validated is full of questions that people ask when (1) the signs of correlations/parameter values change between univariate and multivariate analyses; (2) the statistical significance of parameters (i.e., whether their p-value is above or below some pre-specified threshold) changes; (3) the parameters/correlations have the 'wrong' sign, i.e. disagree with domain knowledge about what the unconditional/independent effect of the predictor should be, e.g.:

"Wrong Sign" On Regression Coefficients - Hierarchical Multiple Linear Regression
Regression coefficients have a different sign for highly correlated predictors
Coefficients change signs
Significance in multiple regression but not in single regression
Regression coefficients seem to have the wrong sign; can I force them to have a specific sign?


Ben Bolker, thanks for the detailed explanation. As far as I understand, in general I use the "offset(log…)" function correctly in my case, when "density" = "birds" / "area". Another question. Will "offset(log…)" work if the dependent variable contains positive integers, as well as several zeros (no birds)?

It should work fine. It won't work if area is zero (in which case you would expect to see zero birds; if so, you get no information, and if you see >0 birds in an area of zero then something else is wrong ...
